# using long file names in RPG programs

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I would like to use db2/SQL created long file name in RPG program (OS V7.1 or v7.2).  I cannot create table with over 10 characters using legacy DDS but Db2/SQL allows me to create tables with long file names. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP.VERYLONGNAMETABLE (COLUMN1 CHAR (30) NOT NULL 
WITH DEFAULT)                                           
RCDFMT VERYRC
```

When I do a work with object command , I see OS recognizes table not as VERYLONGNAMETABLE but as VERYL00001.

If I try to use VERYL00001 name in RPG this works:

```
         DCL-F VERYL00001 DISK(*EXT) USAGE(*INPUT)'
```

but this fails, because of RPG's 10 character limit:

```
         DCL-F VERYLONGNAMETABLE DISK(*EXT) USAGE(*INPUT)
```

but I can do this which gives me internal long name but points to external 10 character short name.

```
    DCL-F VERYLONGNAMETABLE  DISK(*EXT) USAGE(*INPUT)
         extfile('extdesc')
         extdesc('VERYL00001')  ;
```

The worrying thing about this is that if I delete VERYL00001 object, and create new table called VERYLONGNAMETABLE_2, OS gives me same VERYL00001 name. This is very worrying because of confusion that it may cause.

I read that I can do and use ALIAS.

```
 CREATE ALIAS VERYLONG FOR VERYLONGNAMETABLE
```

however this creates a DDMF file, which if I remember from olden days had performance and other issue.

I can also rename (RNMOBJ) VERYL00001 to VERYLONG. Then at least I can have long name for users who want to query on long name, and still use in RPG like this

```
      DCL-F VERYLONGNAMETABLE  DISK(*EXT) USAGE(*INPUT)
            extfile('extdesc')
          extdesc('VERYLONG')  ;
```

or simply:

```
      DCL-F VERYLONG  DISK(*EXT) USAGE(*INPUT)
```

I don't like the fact that each table will be identified by two different names. I am sure that this will cause confusion.

Did I miss any options here?

Comment: It's a mess isn't it. I'd use the ALIAS option. 'Proper' DDM, accessing a different system, is a completely different kettle of fish - the way aliases use them will be fine.

Comment: The CREATE ALIAS command gave me a DDMF file which seems to be a file that points to a local or remote IBM i server. While this gives me a a shorter character name on a long file name, it will probably give me some some headaches that I don't need.

Comment: If it's an alias, it'll only point to the local server, I think. DDM in its 'full' form does lots of good things, but for native IBM i database access only (DRDA is the SQL equivalent). The 'alias' DDMF has your 'confusing short names' configuration management problem, but should be OK otherwise, I'd say.

Answer (score 5):

When you create the table using SQL, you can also specify the system name like so:

```
create table MYLONGTABLENAMEFORTHISTABLE for system name MYTAB12345
(myval char(10))
```

This will allow you to specify the exact object name that can be used in RPG when you want to access it through a `DCL-F MYTAB12345 DISK(*EXT) USAGE(*INPUT)` spec for instance.

This doesn't remove the consideration that all tables will have two names but it at least allows you to control the names to prevent reusing table names.  I don't know of any solution that removes all of these concerns outside of sticking with shorter table names or not using `DCL-F` and just using SQL.  That doesn't really fix the issue that you were trying to handle in the first place though.

Comment: it's a good work around for mess that IBM gave us.  I guess the 10 character rule is here to stay,  It would be huge undertaking to expand it everywhere. BTW: is there a system table somewhere that maps long name to short name?

Comment: I think the information is available in `SYSTABLES`.  If I have this right, the long name is `NAME` and the short name is `SYS_TNAME`.  This is your best resource though: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm